# Set audio output device per application

Tags: 12.10, pulseaudio

Is it possible to configure `PulseAudio`, so that some applications route audio through the headphones, other applications go to the main speakers, and some applications go to both (as it does now)?

Answer (score 1):

go to (ubuntu software center) and search (PulseAudio volume control) or (PulseAudio)

and go terminal and put (alsamixer)

Comment: Neither of these options work. PulseAudio Volume Control allows you select whether to use headphones or speakers, but it's a global setting, not per application. alsamixer doesn't have any options for this.